# Raised Button onClick triggers different function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two components, RaisedButton and TableList. Tablelist return select rows and the same is updated in the state (currentSelectedRows). RaisedButton simply consoles the currentSelectedRows. Now the problem statement:

onClick of RaisedButton it consoles the state properly (using approveSelected) till the time updateSelectedRows does not update the state. Once the state is updated inside updateSelectedRows method, onClick of RaisedButton component first calls updateSelectedRows then approveSelected. Below is the code.

```
export default class MyList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        pendingList:[],
        currentSelectedRows:[]
    }
}updateSelectedRows(selectedRows){
    console.log("updateCalled");
    this.setState({
        currentSelectedRows:selectedRows
    });
};

approveSelected() {
    console.log("approve selected");
    console.log(this.state.currentSelectedRows);
};
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row_align_right">
                <RaisedButton label="APPROVE" backgroundColor={MUIColors.lightGreen500} labelColor={MUIColors.white} onClick={this.approveSelected.bind(this)} />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                <div className="">
                    <TableList
                        selectedRows={this.state.currentSelectedRows}
                        updateSelectedRows={this.updateSelectedRows.bind(this)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Any advice would be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the code for `TableList` so it's hard to know what could be the problem but it seems to work when you just pass a row id upwards to the parent:

```js
const usersList = [
  { name: 'John', age: 33 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 32 },
  { name: 'David', age: 28 },
  { name: 'Eve', age: 29 },
];


class Row extends React.Component {
  onClick = e => {
    const { onClick, rowId } = this.props;
    onClick(rowId)
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <tr onClick={this.onClick}>
        <td>{user.name}</td>
        <td>{user.age}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class TableList extends React.Component {
  onClick = rowId => {
    this.props.updateSelectedRows(rowId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            usersList.map((user, i) => <Row key={i} rowId={i} user={user} onClick={this.onClick}/>)
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class MyList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pendingList: [],
      currentSelectedRows: []
    }
  } updateSelectedRows(selectedRows) {
    console.log("updateCalled");
    this.setState({
      currentSelectedRows: selectedRows
    });
  };

  approveSelected() {
    console.log("approve selected");
    console.log(this.state.currentSelectedRows);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row_align_right">
          <button onClick={this.approveSelected.bind(this)}>Click</button>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          <div className="">
            <TableList
              selectedRows={this.state.currentSelectedRows}
              updateSelectedRows={this.updateSelectedRows.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes the problem was in my TableList code, as I was using <Table> component of Material UI, It has a property of deselectOnClickaway, (which is default true). So the error was, whenever I clicked outside the table component all selected fields were deselected which further triggered my updateSelectedRows method.